# How to convert an image from any format to JPG format?

Tags: asp.net, image

I have tried to use the [ImageFormat class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx) to convert the png format images to JPG format.Then we tried to verify the image with another tool that verifies images and discovered that merely extension is changed but the format remains PNG.

How can we convert the given iamge to JPG format? Are we using the write class? Which methods do we need to invoke. Please provide details.

Also I like to discuss the capabilities of [ImageMagic](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/) in this context.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to re-save the image as the .JPG format.

You can do this using the System.Drawing namespace. Take a look here and see if this does the job http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twss4wb0(v=vs.90).aspx

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Load the image.
        System.Drawing.Image image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\test.bmp");

        // Save the image in JPEG format.
        image1.Save(@"C:\test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        // Save the image in GIF format.
        image1.Save(@"C:\test.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

        // Save the image in PNG format.
        image1.Save(@"C:\test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);        
    }
}
```

Comment: I have given up asking why answers get down-voted. Thanks for the up-vote though! :)

Comment: We did the same thing but missed the encoding part. Please try the above code with setting image encoding parameters as well.

Comment: We don't know what you did because you never posted any code. Post what you have tried if this didn't help.

Comment: This is code not for asp.net, you do not explain how you get/find the file you going to save when you are on an asp.net page, and you do not read from many different file formats to save to jpeg, but you save to many different formats (the opposite). You copy paste what its on the msdn page, but its not relative to this question. Is not a direct helpfull answer to the question.

Comment: @Aristos Do you know what asp.net is? Do you know how to program within the .net framework? Yes I copied and pasted, because sometimes articles on websites are removed, and if so the link would be useless. This is totally relative to the question, although I am not going to just give the complete answer to someone who provided little in the question.